# Grow flower image with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, frontend

I have a flower PNG image and want to grow it on screen.

At first, I set the height from 0 to 100% and the image grew abnormally. I want to grow it according to its structure as I show the direction in the picture.

How can I grow the image according to its nature growing direction?

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask] and post a [mcve]

Comment: Ok, what is the problem?

Comment: If you read [mcve] you know where the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could animate a mask of the same background colour to get this effect.

Here's an example snippet. Run it and press `reveal` to see the result:

```js
function reveal() {
  var maskElement = document.getElementById("mask");
  maskElement.classList.remove("covered");
  maskElement.classList.add("revealed");
}

function cover() {
  var maskElement = document.getElementById("mask");
  maskElement.classList.remove("revealed");
  maskElement.classList.add("covered");
}
```

```css
.flower {
  height: 20rem;
  width: fit-content;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flower img {
  height: 100%;
}

.flower #mask {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -200%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transition: 5s;
}

.flower #mask.covered {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.flower #mask.revealed {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flower">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvoNs.jpg" />
  <div id="mask" class="covered"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="reveal()">reveal</button>
<button onclick="cover()">cover</button>
```